# Which is the efficient method to initialize a char * to nothing in C from the given ones?

Tags: c

The question may seem elementary but it's about a choice.
I have seen these in same code base and got a little confused over the approach.

We do an empty string initialisation so we don't get dereference error (I think).

```
static char *name=(char *)"";
```

and majority cases I have seen this

```
static char *name=NULL;
```

and on rare occasions have seen this too.

```
static char *name=(char *) 0;
```

Can we call any of these practices as standard and is universally recommended? If yes on what logic?

Comment: Please, *please* learn to use `const`.

Comment: There is a tiny performance difference in PIC, in that the first requires a relocation, but that is really not what you should be worried about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two versions with the cast are non-standard; the cast is not necessary in either case (though there is more justification for it in the second of them).

The initializations do two different jobs — both are good jobs, but they are different.

```
static char *name = "";
```

Here, `name` is a valid pointer to an empty string.  It can be passed to functions that expect a valid pointer but where an empty string is sensible.

```
static char *name = NULL;
static char *name = 0;
```

In both these cases, `name` is a null pointer — it doesn't point to anywhere valid.  Dereferencing `name` after either of these initializations leads to undefined behaviour, which means your program typically (but not necessarily) crashes.  You need to make the variable point at something valid before dereferencing it.